# How do i access the POST data that will be generated from an unknown number of list elements (jinja2)

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms

I have created an checklist form that will permit "selects" for each user in my users list. How can i access the data after the post? I am using wtforms, but i cannot add labels here since the length is unknown (so i cannot pre-assign field names in advance).

```
       <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">{{ legend }}</legend>

                {% for user in users %}
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="{{ user.email }}">
                        {{ user.username + ": " + user.email }}
                    </label>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
        </fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
      </div>
```

The code below illustrates the methodology i am typically using to assign variable names to values that i parse through on the POST return.

```py
class GameAssignForm(FlaskForm):
    submit = SubmitField('Click to Complete Assignment')
```

Answer (score 0):

Visit [this](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/processing-incoming-request-data-in-flask) website to checkout how to process in coming request in Flask.